# What are some friendly dismissive ways to respond to compliments?

Tags: modismos

I am looking for some dismissive but friendly ways to respond to compliments instead of just saying "gracias".

Por ejemplo, cuando alguien dice

Eres muy guapo - You are very handsome

- It's a curse. "es una maldición"
- Can't help it. "no puedo evitarlo"
- I try to hide it. "trato de ocultarlo"
- Gets me in trouble some times. "A veces me mete en problemas"

Or for actions

Tu hablas muy bien - You speak very well

- I try "Yo trato". I don't feel like this lands the punch.

Comment: This is not a question about Spanish per se.

Answer (score 1):

Estas frases dependen de muchos contextos, no es lo mismo que las realices con alguien conocido, un buen amigo, un extraño ó un profesor, ya que en algunos casos si la persona no conoce tu carácter o tu forma habitual de actuar, puede que te considere alguien desagradable o simplemente una persona con mala educación, otras se pueden confundir con ironía ó simple sarcasmo, todo depende de los tonos y ante quien se expresan.

A veces un aparente elogio puede resultar una crítica mordaz que incluso puede confundir a los menos avispados.
Esa chica es una belleza, si pero " Es más fina que un coral"...no sabía que en su casa tuviera corales.

- Hablas bien Español, lo intento, pero no se si acabare dominándolo.
- Eres muy guapa, te invito a una copa. - No gracias.
- Contigo tendría diez hijos - Te sientes solo ¿no?.
- Querría decirte dos cosas, que me caes muy bien y la otra no me acuerdo - Me fascina tu capacidad de oratoria.
- A veces me metí en problemas - Creo que siempre has estado metido en problemas.
- Eres muy guapo - Si, pero tu no tanto, tu pareces más bella.
- Es una maldición - Con quien te habrás juntado en este tiempo, yo estoy perfectamente, ya te dije que no eran buena compañía.
- Montas muy bien a caballo - Si, de pequeño juagaba con los centauros.
- Oye podría hablar contigo a solas - Espera....., espera...oyes?, ¡no!, el silencio....¡si!, pues en otro momento será.
- No puedo evitarlo - ¿Has intentado extirparlo o ponerle una rosca? (o alguna conducta muy invasiva o que haga daño, depende de lo que no pueda evitar) ó no te preocupes sácalo todo al exterior.
- Trato de ocultarlo - Si, siempre lo llevarás oculto, hasta yo mismo no sabré que estabas ocultando.
- A mi amigo siempre le toca bailar con la más fea - ¿Por qué será?
- Hice una promesa a mi padre muerto hace 20 años y aún no la he cumplido - Ya va siendo hora ¿no?.
- Esto fue la gota que derramó el vaso de agua - ¿Y donde fue a parar?
- Mi tío es la oveja negra de la familia - No entiendo de lanas.

Como veras todo depende del hábito que tengas, de la confianza en las relaciones, de los lugares en donde se desarrollen, las costumbres lingüísticas que existan en ciertas zonas y sobre todo de las personas. Estas formas a la vez amistosas y un tanto desapacibles ó agridulces de responder, no son fáciles de responder, pues no todos interpretamos los cumplidos y sus respuestas de la misma forma.

- *Es una lástima que las pastillas contra la grosería todavía no se hayan inventado*
- "*Nadie diría que te han educado bien*".
- ¿*Dónde crees que vas? ¿No ves nada a tu alrededor? - Sí, no veo nada. Es extraño que no te des cuenta, hoy olvidé las gafas en casa*.
- ¿*Vas a tardar mucho tiempo más? - Bueno, atrápame aquel pantalón también*.
- Tengo 74 años, ¿soy demasiado mayor para hacerme coletas? - Ni confirmo ni desmiento ó tu estas siempre guapa con todo lo que te hasgas.

Comment: ¿Cómo responde esto a la pregunta?